# "ORA-01109 database did not open" error while configuring Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ubuntu-14.04

I am currently having issues configuring Oracle DB 11g on Ubuntu 14.04. I have successfully installed Oracle but the problem comes when I start configuring it.

First it was a invalid listener issue, after some extensive searching I found out that I had to put my domain name on 127.0.0.1 which I did (my domain name also contains dashes). After I made those changes, I ran into another error:

```
ORA-01109 database not open
```

I have had no luck with this one. What causes the "database not open" error and how could I fix it?

Comment: It is not a listener related problem. You database is in NOMOUNT or MOUNT state. You have to put in in OPEN state!

Comment: here's a link where startup states are described: http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/starting_database.htm

Comment: If you're a beginner, it's not a bad idea to start with the easiest commands first, and those are : `startup` and `shutdown`. Tell us what happens if you run either. Even when these commands are very basic, they would allow you to get a database into a stable situation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
```

It should work I guess.

Or Give this a try

```
$ sqlplus sys/Change12345@orc01 as sysdba

SQL> shut immediate

SQL> startup
```

and check the status of the instance use

```
SQL> select status from v$instance;
```

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error