# Error provisioning namespace. ORA-20001 Request could not be processed at Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I finally managed to install Oracle Apex 5.1.2 but I have problem with creating a workspace. Whenever I try to do so at the end I get an error:
[image: Error provisioning workspace. ORA-20001: Request could not be processed. PROVISION_COMPANY]
I tried to create this workspace with following values:
[image]
The strange thing is that when I try to use `Yes` as option to `Reuse Existing Schema` no schemas are listed. Is it possible that Apex somehow doesn't have access to managing schemas?

I am using APEX with ORDS. At home page I get info that I have 1 workspace and 1 schema.

I've tried:

- Using strong passwords as mentioned [here](https://www.eehelp.com/question/cannot-find-how-to-create-the-new-workspace-apex-3-1/)
- Changing provisioning type to request: Effect is the same. If user request a space and I accept it I get the exact same error.
- Enabled `OMF` with parameter `DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST = '/u01/app/oracle/oradata'` -> *.dbf files are not created before and after the change in directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was installing APEX both on CDB$ROOT, so as a result, and on PDB1. I uninstalled APEX from root, repaired with `@utlrp.sql` script as in [this tutorial](https://mikedietrichde.com/2015/11/19/why-you-should-remove-apex-from-the-cdbroot/) and installed APEX again, but **only on PDB1**. Workspace was successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (apex 18.1/ords) in a database without CDB configured. The solution in my case was to run @apex_rest_config.sql script.
After that, the workspace is created without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem at `ORACLE 12c`, according to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28114588/4294399) link my problem has been solved. The problem is the users can't create workspace in `CDB`, so you must change session container to pdf files by the following steps :

```
$root> cd ~/TEMP/apex

$root> sqlplus 
Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password: 

SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(0); /*set port*/
SQL> alter session set container=YOURAPPEXPDB;
SQL> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(8181);
SQL> alter system register;

//install oracle apex again
```

to remove oracle apex i use [this](https://smarttechways.com/2018/05/27/install-and-remove-apex-from-cdb-pdb-databases-oracle/) link, its perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinstall apex to move it from the CDB to the PDB I suggest you try setting PDB mapping in your ords config file.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/20.2/aelig/configuring-REST-data-services.html#GUID-694B2F89-CE4F-4AB0-88E2-EB35D03DEC3C

I did it by adding
`<entry key="db.serviceNameSuffix"></entry>`
to the end of my defaults.xml (you can find its location by running
`$ java -jar ords.war configdir` ).

Then access apex with /yourpdb in the path: e.g.
`http://server:port/ords/pdb1`
This will run apex from that PDB instead of from the CDB and will create the workspace in there, that should work OK. It did for me.